# xamarin.form (portable xaml.form cross-platform) -on android, SearchBar and StackLayout not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I simply don't know why SearchBar won't display on StackLayout
I've written the following xaml tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
         x:Class="App3.MainPage">

  <StackLayout>
    <SearchBar IsVisible="True" IsEnabled="True" Placeholder="Search" 
     BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White"/>
    <Label Text="asdasd "/>

  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

but the only thing i see is the label and not the searchbar, as you see i've added the IsVisible and IsEnabled properties even though it's redundant just to make sure that's the problem,
notice that if I place the searchbar alone it works fine:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
         x:Class="App3.MainPage">

    <SearchBar  Placeholder="shsdfdsf"/>

</ContentPage>
```

it's also working fine on absolutelayout, thanks for all the helpers !

Comment: @jstreet , not for me, that's why i'm asking...

Comment: @jstreet it's the same xaml for all 3 cases: if i use stacklayout it doesn't work but if i use absolutelayout or no layout it does work fine, in all cases it's there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127954/discussion-between-liora-and-jstreet).

Comment: @jstreet , ty for the attempt but the project is the default blank xamarin.form xaml portable project , the code-behind files got nothing special behind it, the android properties are from api14 to nougat(24) with the added attribute [assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] to make sure xaml mistakes will show compilation errors, but no compilation errors are present in the project even without that attribute and the default state of properties it still didn't work (only within stacklayout), id be glad to add any additional info that might solve this

Comment: just one but I can't find a solution to it that works the warning is "The referenced component 'System.ObjectModel' could not be found." but from digging stackof and their forums no solution worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i've figured it out, apparently unlike label/button and many other it doesn't "fit" the requestHeight and the requestwidth properties of searchbar(or at least here - though it's odd since it should act the same everywhere) 
but writing:

```
    <SearchBar Placeholder="asdasdasf23" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HeightRequest="50" />
```

there fixed it, but if there's someone else who knows why it didn't work w/o that it would be great if I can hear how to fix it.